# FileNotFoundException on PDF files when detecting mime type using Apache Tika

Tags: java, mime-types, apache-tika

is this a bug like the `Files.probeContentType()`?

I have been trying to upload a *.pdf* file but the `FileNotFoundException` is displayed.

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, both `Files.probeContentType()` and `Tika.detect()` can't detect a *.pdf* file.

```
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {

            DiskFileItemFactory diskFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

            ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(diskFactory);

try {
                List<FileItem> fileList = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
                  for (FileItem file : fileList) {
                    if (!file.isFormField()) {
                       String name = new File(file.getName()).getName();
                        File image = new File(request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("UploadPath") + File.separator + name);

                        Tika tika = new Tika();
                        String mimeType = tika.detect(image);
                        System.out.println(mimeType);
}
```

If this is not a bug, how can I fix this?

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: on this line String mimeType = tika.detect(image);

Comment: Is the file in the correct location? As most likely `image` points to a nonexistent file.

Comment: The file is non-existing when I'm trying to detect the mime type. I added the
file.write(new File(request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("UploadPath") + File.separator + name));
before the creation of the 'image' file.

The problem is now fixed. Thanks @meskobalazs